# Matching string that contains asterisk

Tags: php, regex

I know this sounds easy but I am stuck.
I want to match strings that has asterisk `*`.

Essentially I want to allow strings having asterisk at front/back/both but not middle:
(At max there will be 2 asterisks, front and both but no middle, and the presence string is a must)

ALLOW:

> *string*
>  *string
>  string*
>  string

DENY:

> *str*ing*
>   *str*ing
>  str*ing*
>  str*ing
>   *string**
> **
> *

I tried

```
^\\*?((?!\\*).)*\\\*?$
```

and somehow it works.
Can someone explains how this works?
And verify if this is correct because regex..hard to debug and check..

Comment: Your current pattern looks invalid - you need to escape `*`s to match literal `*`s

Comment: Strange to use that method, though, use a negative character set instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
^\*?\w+\*?$
```

demo: https://regex101.com/r/vwuXv2/1/

Explanations:

- `^` anchor imposing the start of a line
- `\*?` a `*` appearing at most one time
- `\w+` at least 1 word char appearing in the text ([a-zA-Z0-9_] feel free to change it depending on your need)
- `\*?` a `*` appearing at most one time
- `$` end of line anchor

Now if you are interested in partial line matches, you can use the following regex:

```
(?<=^| )\*?\w+\*?(?=$| )
```

demo: https://regex101.com/r/vwuXv2/2/

Explanations: you add lookbehind, lookahead assertions.

Adding Japanese characters as requested in the comment (add in `[^*\s]` all the characters you need to exclude from the words):

```
^\*?[^*\s]+\*?$
```

demo: https://regex101.com/r/RaCmwt/1/

or

```
^\*?[[:alpha:]]+\*?$
```

(with unicode flag enabled) or just

```
^\*?\p{L}+\*?$
```

demo: https://regex101.com/r/RaCmwt/2/

Comment: The upper one seems like it make sense. What if the \w+ part is a japanese character?

Comment: @Salam.MSaif: I have edited my comment to add Japanese characters, other non ascii characters. Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply say: Optionally start with asterisk, 0 or more arbitrary characters except asterisk, optionally end with asterisk.

```
^\*?[^*]*\*?$
```

https://regex101.com/r/bibCEc/2

An alternative is to inverse the match and test if there is not ( i.e. `if(!...)`) any asterisk *not* at the begin or end using negative look behind and look ahead:

```
(?<!^)\*(?!$)
```

https://regex101.com/r/8St0M4/2

---

According to your recent edit you would use the quatifier `+` to match **1** or more characters:

```
^\*?[^*]+\*?$
```

https://regex101.com/r/bibCEc/3

Comment: watch out `**` will be accepted by your regex! As well as `*\n*`!

Comment: @Allan That's actually intended according to the qunatifier in the example of the question. I had `+` before in the first version https://regex101.com/r/bibCEc/1 There's no example that `**` should be denied.